# Performance issue of stored procedure with several select and insert operations in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, database-design

My application and database design could be simplified as a simple quotation systems.

Below is detailed descriptions:

Three tables in the database:

**Table: Item:**

- itemId(unique,primary-key,auto-increase)
- name varchar not null
- category varchar not null
- description varchar not null

**Table: Recipient:**

- recipientId(unique,primary-key,auto-increase)
- first name varchar not null
- last name varchar not null
- address varchar not null
- email varchar not null

**Table: Order:**

- id(unique,primary-key,auto-increase)
- price double not null
- date Timestamp
- itemId(not foreign-key)
- recipientId(not foreign-key)

And I have the following stored procedure to handle the select/business logic:

```
CREATE procedere spInsert
   --list of parameters
   set @tmpItemId = (select itemId from item 
                     where name = @name 
                       and category = @category 
                       and description = @description)

   if @tmpItemId is NULL
   begin 
       insert to item values(@name, @category, @description)
       set @tmpItemId = @@IDENTITY
   end

   set @tmpRecipentId = (select recipentId from recipient 
                         where firstname = @firstname 
                           and lastname = @lastname 
                           and address = @address and email = @email )

   if @tmpRecipentId is NULL
   begin 
       insert to recipient values(@firstname, @lastname, @address, @email)
       set @tmpRecipentId = @@IDENTITY
   end

   insert into order values(@price, @date, @tmpItemId, @tmpRecipientId )
```

So basically the logic is checking the existence of `Item` and `Recipient` and then insert.

In the real database, the column numbers of `Item` and `Recipient` are 20,20 respectively. I'm trying to do the stress test by reading a large amount of raw information (which is mixing the item information and recipient information and order information together) in text file and then perform the `spInsert`:

```
JdbcTemplate jt = getJdbcTemplate();
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jt);
simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("spInsert").execute(paraMap);
```

But the speed is not satisfactory. By my rough calculation, it takes 3-5 seconds for inserting every 100 lines of raw information.

I'm wondering if there's any room for improvement? Including changing the design of database?

PS, I'm thinking about changing the auto-increase indexed Id of `Item` and `Recipient` to UUID instead, in order to let the program know the new Id `Item` and `Recipient` and avoid the `select` in the stored procedure. Is it a feasible approach?

---

Here is the execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Execution plans please. Do you expect us to rebuild your database and do your work of getting an execution plan? LIkely you missi ndices to make your query efficient, but we at least should know the execution plan. And you miss the "with recompile" options that a SP like this likely needs to avoid parameter sniffing issues.

Comment: Please refer to the update with execution plan

Comment: He's not getting bad exec plan because of parameter sniffing, but rather because of no indexes at all, and probably won't even after he creates the necessary ones. BTW, avoid WITH RECOMPILE, if you really have to deal with bad cached plan issues do it on statement level, using OPTION (RECOMPILE), much less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need the following indexes for performance:

```
item(name, category, description)
recipient(firstname, lastname, address, email)
```

You should probably make these unique indexes as well, so you avoid the problem of "subquery returns too many rows".

Comment: As mentioned, I'm talking about 20 columns in reality. Is it making unique index of combination of 20 columns a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simplified version, you're actually comparing ~20 columns to find if there's a match before every insert into Item table, and the same for Recipient table? Is it possible to rethink the design? Maybe separate insertion into Items from Recipients and from Orders?

To check what's actually going on inspect the execution plan and the output of SET STATISTICS IO ON. My guess is that the search part is the problem.

The tables are clustered on identity columns, I believe. Create nonclustered index on one or maybe two most selective columns to speed up searching. Don't make the index too wide because you'll slow it down. You won't be able to make it unique, but safeguard the subqueries with SELECT TOP 1.

Don't ever use @@IDENTITY, use scope_identity() instead.

Comment: the number of columns is large so I have no choice but compare one by one. I'd like to redesign but have no clue. And do you mean create separate stored procedures for `Item`, `Recipient` and `Order`?  Please refer to the updated execution plan.

Comment: The exec plan is as expected, table (clustered index) scan, in absence of useful indexes. Choose the most selective column or the combination of and create NC index on it, this might in fact be enough improvement.

Comment: I try to create clustered index in `Item` table for testing but it said that there's already a clustered index in the table, which is the `itemId`. Should I change the `itemId` to non-clustered index and put 2-4 coulumns to clustered index?

Comment: No, your current clustered index (on identity column) is OK, leave it as is; otherwise you will significantly slow down the inserts and introduce fragmentation. Create a nonclustered index on relevant highly selective columns (as few as possible) instead.

Comment: How about using UUID instead of auto-increase id? In this way, I could handle the table relationships in server side and the stored procedure is just responsible for insertion

Comment: It is important that the clustering key is not random, but increasing. If you can create a sequential UID, should be OK. In SQL Server 2012, I'd suggest using sequence object.

Comment: A little improvement is achieved. It take 3 seconds to insert 100 rows. Any room for improvement. I remember in `C#` there's TVP which could be fast for insertion.

Comment: How about group 50 or 100 insertion into one transaction and commit this transaction?

Comment: BTW, within the stored procedure, if I put the `select` ahead and then `Insert`. Does it help?

Comment: Which indexes did you create?

Comment: In reality, I create non clustered indexes base on just 1-2 columns with data type varchar.

Comment: What the execution plans look like now? It would be ideal if you could upload XML version of exec plan.

Comment: Thx for help, dean. If I test the program in my local PC, the result is still OK, 1 sec for 100 message insertion. But if I test the program in UAT machine and db is located in other machine. It takes 5 sec for 100 message which becomes unacceptable. How to investigate this?